# HTML5 'required' not working with submit button

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

The form wont submit when `required` is added to the tags, but when removed, it will work. Why is this happening and is there a fix? Thanks.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="insert.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" style="">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fname">Firstname*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="lname">Surname*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>          

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Gender*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3"> 
        <select name="gender" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Age Group*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select name="age_group" id="age_group" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="child">Child (0 - 12)</option>
          <option value="youth" >Youth (13 - 17)</option>
          <option value="adult">Adult (18 - 49)</option>
          <option value="elder">Elder ( 50+ )</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Status:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
          <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="single">Single</option>
          <option value="single_parent" >Single Parent</option>
          <option value="married">Married</option>
          <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
          <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">D.O.B.*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select name="day" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Day --</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option>
          <option value="23">23</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="29">29</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select name="month" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Month --</option>
          <option value="01">January</option>
          <option value="02">February</option>
          <option value="03">March</option>
          <option value="04">April</option>
          <option value="05">May</option>
          <option value="06">June</option>
          <option value="07">July</option>
          <option value="08">August</option>
          <option value="09">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="wed_anni" style="display:none;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Wedding Anniversary:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select name="day" class="form-control" >
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option>
          <option value="23">23</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="29">29</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select name="month" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="01">January</option>
          <option value="02">February</option>
          <option value="03">March</option>
          <option value="04">April</option>
          <option value="05">May</option>
          <option value="06">June</option>
          <option value="07">July</option>
          <option value="08">August</option>
          <option value="09">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Type*:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <select name="type" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>-- Please Select --</option>
          <option value="member">Member</option>
          <option value="worker">Worker</option>
          <option value="hod">H.O.D.</option>
          <option value="minister">Minister</option>
          <option value="ord_minister">Ordained Minister</option>
          <option value="asst_pastor">Asst. Pastor</option>
          <option value="pastor">Pastor</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="johnsmith@yahoo.com">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="16 Fortlawn Avenue">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Mulhuddart">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipco" placeholder="Dublin 15">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="contact1">Contact Num 1:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="contact1" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="contact2">Contact Num 2:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="contact2" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button  value=" Send" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: `required` is for validation, it will not submit the form if a element with `required` is empty. Please provide details under what circumstances your form doesn't submit if it's outside of what's expected.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, I know. I am filling out all the required parts of the form before submitting but its still not working.

Comment: Not working how? Are they any messages from the `required` field?

Comment: No, there are no messages in the required fields.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek http://i.gyazo.com/477623a0607367841c3ab9bc7bac1fed.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the console you should get the following error message:

> An invalid form control with name='month' is not focusable.

This happens because you have an element with `required`, but is being hidden in some way causing the validation to mess up. In this case here is the problem:

```
<div class="form-group" id="wed_anni" style="display:none;">
    ...
    <select name="month" class="form-control" required>
    ....
</div>
```

The `<select>` is hidden by the outer `<div>`. That is causing the problem. One solution is to remove `required` from that field. Another is to remove `style="display:none;"` or show it on submitting.